# What is the sidebar in Android emulator called and how to get it?

Tags: android-emulator

What is the **sidebar** called that is marked with Black color in the Android emulator ?
How to get it in a new emulator ?
[image]

Comment: Your question better suits to StackOverflow.  Move there and don't forget to explain what is "New emulator"

Answer (score 1):

Try to press **F1** ,when emulator is open
it will show you all the shortcut key's for your emulator with that sidebar on right.

Hope it helps ..!